# Why does my JQuery event delegation not work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Easy question for somebody, but I can't figure it out!

I have some jQuery that adds a row to a table, but the input fields that get added have no jQuery events connected to them. Click on the first input and the number 5 goes in. Add a row, click the newly-created row and nothing happens. What am I missing?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74fw0cjn/1/).

HTML:

```
<table id="TodayTable" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td class="start"> 
   <input type="text">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
 
<a href="#" class="addNewRow">Add New Row</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".addNewRow").on('click',function()
{
 $("#TodayTable").append('<tr><td class="start"><input type="text"></td></tr>');
});

$(".start").on('click',function()
{ 
 $(this).find('input').val('5');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right concept but you're not making use of it. [*Event Delegation*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Change:

```
$(".start").on('click',
```

To:

```
$("#TodayTable").on('click', '.start',
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(".addNewRow").on('click',function()
{
 $("#TodayTable").append('<tr><td class="start"><input type="text"></td></tr>');
});

$("#TodayTable").on('click','.start', function()
{ 
 $(this).find('input').val('5');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TodayTable" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td class="start"> 
   <input type="text">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
 
<a href="#" class="addNewRow">Add New Row</a>
```